# Simple Issue with Arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I was just wondering why the output for this code I have below is `abcdef def` instead of `abc def`.

```
 main()
{
    char array1[3]="abc";
    array1[3]='\0';    

    char array2[3]="def";
    array2[3]='\0';

    printf("%s  %s", array1, array2);
}
```

Comment: Give us code that actually works. +your main definition is invalid.

Comment: `char array1[3+1]="abc";` +1 for The end of the string

Comment: `char array1[3] = "abc";` is not allowed in vs2008. I've tried that and `error C2117: 'array1' : array bounds overflow` occurred.

Comment: This invokes UB:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/07/what-is-undefined-behavior.html

Answer (score 6):

```
char array1[3]="abc";
array1[3]='\0';    

char array2[3]="def";
array2[3]='\0';
```

`array1[3]='\0';` and `array2[3]='\0';` statements access arrays out of bounds and invoke undefined behavior. The last element of an array of 3 elements is `array1[2]` not `array[3]`.

To fix your program, declare your arrays as:

```
char array1[]="abc";    
char array2[]="def";
```

And don't manually add the null terminator as it will be already included in the declaration above.

**EDIT**:

some other answers incorrectly assume that

```
char array1[3]="abc";
```

would write a trailing null character outside the array. Actually no trailing null character is written in this initialization. The declaration is equivalent to:

```
char array1[3]= {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

`char array1[3]="abc";`

Then `array1[3]` is out of bounds.

You should do:

```
char array1[4]="abc"; //Remember the '\0'
           ^^^
```

Note that the `'\0'` will be added in this way.

Also please note that when you have array of size `N`, then the indexes are from `0` to `N - 1`.

Comment: *It adds '\0'* actually this is a special case, and no `\0` is added in `char array1[3]="abc";` as the length of the string is the same as the size of the array,

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
 main()
{
    char array1[3]="abc"; //Undefined ,when you access this using printf() with %s

     array1[3]='\0';   //here you are storing value which is out of bound in nature  

    char array2[3]="def"; //same as above
    array2[3]='\0'; //same as above

    printf("%s  %s", array1, array2);
}

memory: 
       ---------------
      | a | b | c |\0|
      ----------------
```

The last \0  what you are putting is more than the space you have allocated.

solution:

```
 main()
{
    char array1[4]="abc"; 
     //array1[3]='\0';  //no need 

    char array2[4]="def";
   // array2[3]='\0'; //no need
 printf("%s  %s", array1, array2);
}
```

It will give desired output

Answer (score 0):

This is such a bad code! What is happening is the following:

Compiler allocated space for 2x3 chars.

```
main()
{
    char array1[3]="abc"; //Will write "abc" in array 1 AND \0 in array2[0]
    array1[3]='\0';       //Out of array!!! (Re)writing \0 in array2[0]

    char array2[3]="def"; //Will write "def" in array2 AND \0 after array2 space, POTTENCIALLY corrupting code!
    array2[3]='\0';       //\0 (re)wrote after array2, POTTENCIALLY corrupting code!
```

What you have in memory is 7 bytes (just 6 were allocated): "abcdef\0".
Pointes still ok: array1 points "a" and array2 points "d".
In C standard libraries, strings sizes are determined by ending zero terminator. So when you printf array1, it will read "abcdef" until \0.

Comment: *Will write "abc" in array 1 AND \0 in array2[0]* this is wrong, no `'\0'` is written. See the edit in my answer.